# How to specify the extension for a downloaded file Laravel 5.0

Tags: php, laravel, file, laravel-5

I am attempting to download a file when the user hits a route, and I was able to do so. However, when the user wants to download a docx or doc file, the file extension doesn't have .doc in it. To better ask my question, my code is below:

```
Route::get('resumeDownload', function() {
    $user = Auth::user();
    $path = $user->cv()->first()->path; //when the user uploads a document, i store
    //the path of it in the database
    $extension = explode(".", $path)[1]; //if the user uploaded a doc, returns .doc etc
    $uploaded = Storage::get($path); //I get it from my storage
    return (new \Illuminate\Http\Response($uploaded, 200))
           ->header('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
});
```

This code works great when the user wants to download a pdf, however for a .doc file or a .docx file, the file which is downloaded has no extension. I also save the extension and can easily retrieve it, if that could help. Is there anyway to make this work for .doc, .docx, .pdf, and .txt?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Content-Disposition` header to specify the name of the downloaded file but there is no need to manually create the download response. Laravel already has a built int function to generate a download response with the proper `Content-Disposition` header

```
$headers = ['Content-Type' => 'application/pdf'];
return response()->download($fileContent, 'filename.pdf', $headers);
```

Comment: Could you tell me how to get $fileContent from my code please??

Comment: file_get_contents($path)